# UISwitch in each sectioned table row's accessoryView

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode4.6, uiswitch, accessoryview

I am new to iOS coding, I looked around here in SO and tried several approaches to solve this, but nothing seems to work. I'm shure it's because of some silly mistake of mine :-)

I have a sectioned table, with about 25 rows in total, divided in 2 sections.
There is a switch for each `cell.accessoryView`, i try to store the switch state, when it changes, in a `NSArray`, but logging the array content at that index weirdly returns `0` in any case.
(The array is instantiated as a property `(nonatomic, readwrite)` of the `TableViewController`, and synthesized)

And obviously , when i scroll the table up and down, all the switches return in the default `OFF` state.

Thanks for any help!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
//countries dict and switch state array init..  
self.countries = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"countries" ofType:@"plist"]];
NSNumber *b = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
for (int i=0; i<210; i++) {
    [statiSwitch addObject:b];
    NSLog(@"%d", [[statiSwitch objectAtIndex:i] integerValue]);
}

//tableview drawing..
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellWithSwitch";    
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

NSString *continent = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section];
NSString *country = [[self.countries valueForKey:continent] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//Simple tag calculation...
NSInteger tagOb = indexPath.section * 100 + indexPath.row;

UISwitch *mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
mySwitch.tag = tagOb;
if ([statiSwitch count] > tagOb) {
    [mySwitch setOn:[[statiSwitch objectAtIndex:tagOb] boolValue] animated:NO];
     }

cell.textLabel.text = country;    
cell.accessoryView = mySwitch;

return cell;
}
```

And then the method called at switch status change:

```
- (void) switchChange:(UISwitch *)sender {
NSNumber *c = [NSNumber numberWithBool:sender.on];
[statiSwitch replaceObjectAtIndex:sender.tag withObject:c];

NSLog(@"switch tag is: %i and state is: %d", sender.tag, sender.on);
NSLog(@"switch states array value: %d", [[statiSwitch objectAtIndex:sender.tag] integerValue]);
}
```

Comment: Try subclassing UITableViewCell, and store the entire cell in an array, instead of just the switch value.  Then, as the tableView scrolls, pull the cell out of the array instead of dequeueing.

Comment: So, i should set up an array with all the (let's say) 20 cell objects, including the accessory switches, and then have the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method take the cells out of that array?

Comment: And you should subclass UITableViewCell, and handle the switch action in that class.  It's just like using an object class to store data.

Comment: OK, i'll try that out! thanks! (if you suggest me some example code for the subclass handling the switch action.. that would be great :-)

Comment: Are you storyboarding, or doing it all in code?  With storyboards, it's a really simple process.

Comment: Actually i began with storyboarding, i.e. putting th switch on the prototype cell, but i had the same problem of switches resetting to OFF state wen scrolled down, so set the prototype cell in the storyboard to be an empty one, and just assigning a Reuseidentifier to it

Comment: See my answer for specifics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you had omitted to initialize statiSwitch before adding objects to it.

In viewDidLoad before the for-loop, add this line

```
statiSwitch = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Comment: I'm going on using the int array.. But you're right @Rick, i forgot to init the array in that code above: `statiSwitch` was declared as a property of the `viewController`, synthesized and so on, that's i why i thought there was no need to alloc and inizialize it again.

Comment: No worries, just keep this in mind. There will be many situations where you will still need to use NSMutableArrays. You can't always stick to C if you want to learn iOS programming. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up a custom cell class.
2. Create a prototype cell in your storyboard, and place a switch in it.
3. Set the prototype cell to your custom class, and set a reuse identifier.
4. Connect the switch to an IBOutlet in your custom cell class.
   (Also set up @protocol and delegate if you want your cell to be able to communicate)
5. Now for the tricky/hackish part:

In -viewDidLoad:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.cellDataArray count]; ++i) {
            CustomCell *cell;

    cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:nil];
    cell.delegate = self;
    [self.cellsArray addObject:cell];
}
```

1. In your cellForRowAtIndexPath, do the following:

   cell = self.cellsArray[indexPath.row]; // or .item if using a collectionView
2. Since the switch is connected to each cell, you need a method in your CustomCell class that will do something based on the switch, and perhaps send a call to the delegate class.

Comment: Thanks a lot! i'll try and let you know.

Comment: i tried that way, it was fine with the cell array and the rest, but i had compiler warnings with the line `cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:nil];`, placing it inside the `-viewDidLoad:` method. it told me that `tableView` doesn't have any identifier for the `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:`. I solved it with a workaround, using a simple int array to store switches values.. don't know it wasn't working storing values in NSMutableArray of NSObjects.. see my answer for details.

Comment: If you had changed @"Cell" to @"CellWithSwitch", you wouldn't have had that problem.

Comment: in my answer i wrote "@Cella" and not "@CellWithSwitch" because that was the new identifier i used both in the storyboard and in the edited "table view controller" .m file

Answer (score 0):

I used a simple `int array` to store the switches values, it appears to work better than a `NSMutableArray` made up of objects with switchTag and switchState properties, which is what i used to do before.

Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    //[here goes the code to retrieve my table data from a dictionary, getting sections and rows]

    //int array iniazialization, with zeros to have switches set at OFF at beginning

    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
    switchStates[i] = 0;
        }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cella"; 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

//Cell drawing..

NSString *continent = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section];
NSString *country = [[self.countries valueForKey:continent] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = country;

//Calculate the tag to be assigned to the switches..

    switchTag = indexPath.section * 100 + indexPath.row
    UISwitch *mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    mySwitch.tag = switchTag;
    mySwitch.on = switchStates[switchTag];

    cell.accessoryView = mySwitch;

    return cell;

}

//switch change action..

- (void) switchChange:(UISwitch *)sender {
     switchStates[sender.tag] = sender.on;
}
```

Now i have "just" to store those switch values in core data.. see you here for my upcoming questions :-)